# What does it mean when building an iOS app to "install the app"

Tags: xcode

I see this mentioned in multiple places "only do X during install" but in XCode 4.5 I don't even see an "install" option. Is this something to do with preparing an app for distribution, or something to do with copying the App into simulator/device for testing?

An official link covering this would be great... my web searches aren't turning up much definitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS apps, the install step is executed during Archive (or by running `xcodebuild install`), and installs the package into `INSTALL_PATH` (Installation Directory) under `DSTROOT`. The archive step overrides `DSTROOT` to point into the package it's creating.

It's controllable using the "Skip Install" option ([`SKIP_INSTALL` in xcconfig](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html)). This should generally be No, since you do want to install the package during archiving.

It is unusual to configure the installation step on iOS, but is more common on Mac if you need to build a package installer.